# Assign the value of an object in another object

Tags: c#

I have two classes class A and class B and a static list as show below

```
class A
{
   int Id;
   string firstName;
   string lastName;
}

class B
{
   int Id;
   A a;
   string value;
}

class c
{
    public static List<A> obj=new List<A>();
}
```

I need to assign the value of an item from the list 'obj' to the property a in an object of class B and not the reference of the item in the list.

Comment: Do you mean you need to clone the object ?

Comment: @Adham Modification is made to the object after assigning it to the property a in class B and i don't need this modifiction to be reflected in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The list 'obj' only contains references.

If you start cloning the instances of A (from the list to the 'B.a' property) you would have 2 instances with the same Id...

In other words your requirement is contradictionary with the fact that A has an ID (and thus a strong identity).

Answer (score 0):

try like this

B b=new B();

C c=new C();

b.a.property= c.obj[i].property;